# Is there a way to automate adding gallery application in azure active directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are using SSO between applications hosted on azure using azure active directory for authentication and salesforce. For that we have configured azure active directory as well as salesforce with the steps provided in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-saas-salesforce-tutorial/).
But now I have a requirement to automate these steps using powershell or graph api.
Nothing is given about in azure graph api documentation or powershell for azure active directory.
Has anyone tried this or has any solution?

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me around this.

Comment: Typically this is only done once, so automation doesn't really provide too much value. Could you elaborate on the scenario that calls for automating this? Do you want to automate the entire process, or just the AAD portions?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have entire azure deployment being set up using powershell. As part of this I would like to have E2E process set up starting from adding salesforce app, Configure single sign on, enable user provisioning.